# Linear Independence and replacement of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I hope you are doing well :) I am currently working on  the following exercise:

"Is it possible to replace two of the following vectors: $$ u_{1} = (1,1,0,0), u_{2} = (1,0,0,1), u_{3} = (0,1,1,0), u_{4} = (0,0,1,1) $$  ,in the real vectorspace R^4, with the vectors $$v_{1} = (1,-1,1,3),  v_{2}= (2,-3,-2,3) $$ such that the resulting four vectors are all linearly independent ?"

I first decided on solving the general Matrix for all u-Vectors; which concluded in showing the following, after subsequently row reducing and solving the Matrix:

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

$$ L = \{b * (1,-1,-1,1) | b \in \mathbb{R}\} $$

indicating that the Rank(A) = 3 and therefore implying the linear dependence between all four vectors. Further, one would have to replace one of the vectors (for example u4), such that we would be able to establish a linear independence between three of the remaining u-vectors and a vector v = (a,b,c,d) (with a,b,c,d being real numbers) if the Matrix A will be:

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & a\\
0 & -1 & 1 & -a+b \\
0 & 0 & 1 & c \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -a+b-c+d\\
\end{pmatrix}$

By try and error I have found that if I were to replace any of the u-vectors with one v-Vector, that the resulting four Vectors have yet not been linearly independent.Though generally, I am unsure on how I shall continue or if all what I have discovered so far will even lead me on the right track. As always I appreciate all help, comments and suggestions (I also find it very helpful if one can refer to a precise criterion/lemma/proposition) and I apologize in advance for the messy formatting; please be kind

Comment: All six of the vectors are contained in the subspace $\{x\in\mathbb R^4:\;x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4=0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ ways of choosing the 2 vectors that are being replaced. Go over all 6 possibilities and do what you did with the matrix for all $u$ vectors.